# How to override ctrl-p and ctrl-n in RStudio on OS X?

Tags: r, rstudio, keyboard-shortcuts

The keyboard shortcuts to up-arrow (ctrl-p) and down-arrow (ctrl-n) save me enormous amounts of time instead of looking around for the arrow keys themselves (and moving my hand over there). Arrow keys vary between keyboards and do not lend themselves to touch-typing.

Sadly, RStudio has chosen to break this pretty much system-wide standard for cursor movement with some little-used special commands.  I have tried both system-level and using the software BetterTouchTool to make ctrl-p and ctrl-n do what they should in RStudio, but nothing so far tried works, even after restarting RStudio.

Any answers?  Otherwise, back to Textmate and regular R, which is awkward bc RStudio is multiplatform and workable for teaching, whereas Textmate isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had no trouble using [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/) to override the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> shortcuts to send <kbd>⬆︎</kbd> and <kbd>⬇︎</kbd>, respectively. As you know, it is commercial software.

1. Open BetterTouchTool, and click the + button in the lower left. "Select an app from running apps" and then choose RStudio.
2. Make sure RStudio is selected. Then click + in the Groups & Top Level Triggers pane.
3. On the right hand side, click into the "Click here to record a shortcut" and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.
4. Click the + in the "Actions Assigned to Selected Trigger".
5. Expand "Send Keyboard Shortcut" and click to record <kbd>⬆︎</kbd>.
6. Repeat the process for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!! Knowing that it does work was the key.  It turned out it was not working for me because I had recorded a key sequence (ctrlkey down, p down, p up, ctrlkey up) instead of a shortcut.  Changing to recording a shortcut instead fixed the issue.  IDK why the other didn't work, but maybe variation in key sequence.